# High performance markers on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, performance, markers

I'm using Leaflet to visualize a large number of points on a map. The points don't need to be very fancy, I just need to be able to set a radius (doesn't matter if it's pixels or meters, I just need relative size differences), and a color on them.

So I'm thinking that L.Circle and L.CircleMarker are overkill for this purpose. With 7000 points, the map lags quite a lot. Are there any markers that are more light-weight than L.Circle/L.CircleMarker? Some kind of markers that doesn't need complicated radius calculations or a lot of different drawing settings?

If not, any other way I can get better performance with that many markers? I tried with a [conditionalLayer](https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-conditionalLayer), but it's too slow to update, since it has to remove and re-add everything for every zoom or pan (which takes 2-3 seconds every time). It is important that I am able to show all the markers (up to 10 000) when zoomed out.

(Note: I have already activated the L_PREFER_CANVAS setting, which did make a difference, but it's still laggy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem is not that "markers are overkill", but rather that the redraw updates are killing your performance.

Approaches to tiling the rendering calls such as https://carto.com/torque/ or https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid (particularly VectorGrid.Slicer for this use case) should help minimize the redraws.

Otherwise, consider using a different visualization such as clustering or heatmaps.